# Google sheet: how to add the cell's value to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, cell, addition

I want to create a function that could add the value of the current cell to another cell if a condition is met.

From this [Help Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gXQN.png)

to this [Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzbHM.png)

I intend to keep on adding data and thought it would be better to assign the right function for each cell in the 'total' column. I think I can use IF() to select cells per A, B, and C, but not sure what to do with adding each 'total' value from 'TRACKER' to the corresponding cell in 'WALLET' And still couldn't find the right function after three days of search, and I decided to finally join and ask for your help.

Please save me

Comment: You can use `INDEX/MATCH`, `FILTER` function. Post data as text table or share a workbook.

Comment: Please check your sheet.

Comment: If it helps then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SUMIFS()` function like-

```
=SUMIFS($F$14:$F$23,$C$14:$C$23,$B$6,$B$14:$B$23,C6)
```

See your sheet.

[image]

Comment: I want to use SEARCH() to find cells with certain text. I know that the function allows to set up a starting point, but can you assign an ending point?

Answer (score 0):

If name and letter are repeated you can use `=SUMIFS()`. Maybe you can use a pivot table instead of the three tables.